# Deconstruct this veriable in JS for Clean Code

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I am trying to make my code as clean as possible and I want to deconstruct and make it one line/shorter. I don't like that I wrote `data.id` over and over in the object.

```
let { data } = await api.getCity(cityName, units) // database call
data = {id: data.id, name: data.name, country: data.sys['country'], main: data.main, weather: data.weather[0]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: “Clean” code isn’t code that’s the least number of lines possible. High-level languages like JavaScript are for humans, so readable code is much more preferable to “ultra-optimised” code; even if the former does take a couple of more lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only modifying country and weather you can do:

```js
let { data } = await api.getCity(cityName, units) // database call
data = {...data, country: data.sys['country'], weather: data.weather[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this instead

```
...
const data = await api.getCity(cityName, units)
const {id, name, sys, main} = data
let newData = {id, name, sys}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would significantly improving readability; anyway here is the one liner deconstructing:

```
let { data: {id, name, main, sys:{ country }, weather: [weather] }} = await api.getCity(cityName, units) // database call
```

```js
const mockData = { 
  data: { 
    id: '1', 
    name: 'john', 
    main: 'something',
    sys: { 
      country: 'International',
      foo: 'bar'
    },
    weather: ['city1-rainy', 'city2-sunny']
   }
 };
 
let { data: {id, name, main, sys:{ country }, weather: [weather] }} = mockData;

console.log('id', id)
console.log('name', name)
console.log('main', main)
console.log('country', country)
console.log('weather', weather)
```